# Can I convert Garmin .img maps to a format that can be displayed on an Android phone?

Tags: android, gps

I would like to be able to use the contour maps that are available at http://www.smc.org.uk/ContourMaps.php on my phone. I read on the QLandcarteGT wiki that this file format is closed. I am a total noob when it comes to digital maps, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Will try Img2ozi in Wine and display the maps using Rmaps or Androzic(when I get a chance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this on the OpenStreetMap wiki pages, might be worth a try?
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/VGPS